# What is the safest way to copy all subdirectories and their contents on Unix?

Tags: linux, unix, directory, copy, cp

What is the safest way to copy all subdirectories and their contents on Unix to another directory somewhere else? For example:

```
     root                           some other directory
    /   \                             /           \
dir_1 .. dir_n  --(copy to) --->   to be filled with those copied 
                                   directories
```

Not only would I like to copy the directories but also copy the contents inside them. Also, it is imperative that in no way do I move the directories from their original location, hence why I want to copy.

Comment: What about 'cp -R'?

Comment: You can use also 'rsync -a'. It works even to copy files/directories to a remote machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
cp -r
```

-R, -r, --recursive
copy directories recursively

you can look up a commands syntax / Parameters by looking in the Manual of the command with `man {name of your command}`